# Console Application output is not shown

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, psexec

I have read several questions in StackOverflow about redirecting output/errors
from application but It could not help me.

I have developed an executable in C# code. It recovers software from system registry
and call a webservice to save it to our database.

Inside the executable we are printing messages with

> Console.WriteLine("Message from Executable");

On the other hand we have a CRM application and I have written two win forms
that call psexec.exe with the desired parameters and this .exe is remotely 
copied and launched on target machine.

If you use direct psexec call with that parameters in cmd.exe, we can see the psexec
execution banners and OUR executable output

Something like:

> PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
>
> Copyright (C) 2001-2010
>
> Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> Enterprise software @ 2012
>
> **Message from application**
>
> Starting task in machine "XXXXXXX"
>
> Recovering software list from registry
>
> Program.exe exited on MACHINE with error code 0.

When I make the psexec call with .NET, I cant recover my application output, It
just shows:

> PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
>
> Copyright (C) 2001-2010
>
> Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> Program.exe exited on MACHINE with error code 0.

I am assigning to Process class a delegate who is recovering async
data from process, but this information, is not there.

I paste some code to see If you can find the reason my C# Console application
output does not appear:

The command I launch is:

```
Dim CmdExe As String = "\\#MAQUINA# -u #USUARIO# -p #CLAVE# -s -c -f """ + executionPath + """"
```

Parametes -s (Run as system) -c (Copy local file to remote system) -f (force overwrite)

```
Private Sub LanzarProceso()
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        Dim Proceso As New Process
        AddHandler Proceso.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf CallbackProcesoAsync
        AddHandler Proceso.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorDataReceivedAsync

        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        startInfo.FileName = execFile
        startInfo.Arguments = CmdExe.Replace("#MAQUINA#", txtFiltroMaquina.Text).Replace _
                                            ("#USUARIO#", txtUsuario.Text.Trim).Replace _
                                            ("#CLAVE#", txtClave.Text.Trim)
        Proceso.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        Proceso.StartInfo = startInfo
        Proceso.Start()
        Proceso.BeginOutputReadLine()
        Proceso.BeginErrorReadLine()
        Proceso.WaitForExit()


    End Sub
```

Delegates handling data:

```
 Private Sub CallbackProcesoAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)

        If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then
            If Not listtask.InvokeRequired Then
                listtask.Items.Add(args.Data.ToString)
            Else
                Dim d As New TextToControl(AddressOf AddToControl)
                listtask.Invoke(d, args.Data.ToString)
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ErrorDataReceivedAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then
            If Not listtask.InvokeRequired Then
                listtask.Items.Add(args.Data.ToString)
            Else
                Dim d As New TextToControl(AddressOf AddToControl)
                listtask.Invoke(d, args.Data.ToString)
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

I checked the program is finishing correctly. THe c# executable has

```
Enviroment.Exit(0);
```

at the end of the execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the best workaround I found to get all the output between psexec and my c# application
after execution is:

> Dim CmdExe As String ="\#MAQUINA# -u #USUARIO# -p #CLAVE# -s -c
>   -f """ + executionPath + """ > outputFileCode.txt"

This allow me to parse the standard output without having to change anything or calling 
my program directly, because I can`t do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the console window is a mix of output sent to console by both psexec as well as the child process. You can intercept the output from psexec, but to do the same for the child would require the interception code in the psexec, which apparently it does not have

Try to remove the intermediary - call your executable directly

Comment: Im trying to call "cmd.exe /c "c:\myprogram" to be the cmd.exe the one who gives me the output but application hangs. THis has to be possible. I can not use other thing that ps exec :/

Comment: +50 bounty for you because you are the only person who tried and answer